# Is the class of all morphisms in a locally small category a set?

Tags: category-theory, set-theory

A category is said to be locally small if each of its hom-sets is a set, i.e., is a set instead of a proper class. But what if we take
$\bigcup_{A,B\in obj \mathscr C} \text{Mor}(A,B)$? Is it also a set?

I think if the catefory is small, which means it is locally small and $obj \mathscr C$ is a set, then $\bigcup_{A,B\in obj \mathscr C} \text{Mor}(A,B)$ is indeed a set.(right?)

Comment: Yes, because then you have set-indexed union of sets. In the first case, though, you'd have a class-indexed union of sets which isn't even technically writable and won't a priori (or typically) be a set, but instead a proper class.

Comment: The common non-small concrete categories are basically all counterexamples. The category of sets with functions, the categories of topological or metric spaces with continuous functions, the category of (abelian or general) groups with group homomorphisms, the category of schemes, and so on. They're all locally small with a proper class of morphisms.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer to question 1 is no: consider a discrete category (= no nonidentity morphisms) with a proper class of objects. Then this is locally small, but the collection of all its morphisms is not a set.

Meanwhile, since the union of set-many sets is a set, a small category has set-many morphisms. (In ZFC the key axioms are the appropriately-named [**union axiom**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Axiom_of_union) - which states that for any set $X$, the collection $$\bigcup X=\{z: \exists y(z\in y\mbox{ and }y\in x)\}$$ is a set - and (an instance of) the axiom of [**replacement**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Axiom_schema_of_replacement), by which we can form the set $\{Hom(A, B): A, B\mbox{ are objects}\}$.

Finally, note that for locally small categories, having set-many objects and having set-many morphisms in total are equivalent: this is because there are at least as many morphisms as there are objects (since each object has an identity morphism).